# Using Gettext and Poedit

Tags: php, internationalization, gettext, poedit

I use Gettext and Poedit for translatating web-applications.

```
$args = array(0 => "about");
$Header['title'] = _("title_".$args[0]);
```

The problem is that it is receiving only "title_".

Comment: Please clarify what's your problem.

Comment: I use poedit, it is not parsing and is receiving only title_. This dynamic content, poedit show only title_, it not working

Answer (score 2):

By “receiving” you probably mean that xgettext/Poedit only *extracts* the string literal from there. Well, xgettext only parses the code to extract literals. It can’t very well somehow magically know what possible values you might pass in as `$args` values, can it? And because it can’t read your mind, it can only extracts what it can see. Frankly, I’d consider it a xgettext bug that it evens extracts “title_” from this.

You can only meaningfully use literals as gettext function arguments.

Comment: (This is a bit of an oversimplification, if you want to know the full story, read the GNU gettext manual to grasp the concepts.)